# Tabla que no se carga con php

Tags: php, html5

Tengo una página donde la intención es cargar una serie de mensajes recibidos por un usuario. Para eso en el principio de carga de la página hago lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$conexion = new Conexion();
$sql = "SELECT id, fecha_hora, remitente, asunto FROM mensajes WHERE destinatario = :valor";
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':valor', $_SESSION['id_usuario']);
$stmt->execute();
?>
```

Más abajo, en el body de la página hago lo siguiente:

```
<table class="ui padded stackable table">
<thead >
    <tr>
        <th hidden>Id</th>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Remitente</th>
        <th>Asunto</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php while($resultado = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>
    <tr>
        <td hidden><?php echo $resultado['id'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['fecha_hora'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['remitente'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resultado['asunto'];?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Lo más extraño de todo esto es que la misma estructura la realizo en otras paginas con otras tablas que lleno con el mismo sistema pero en este caso no carga nada. Hice varias modificaciones para ver que se carguen los datos, de hecho hice el dichoso while a continuación de donde hago el $stmt->execute() y he colocado sendos echo para mostrar los registros y ME LOS MUESTRA !!!... ahora por que no los muestra en la tabla, no entiendo...

---

Miren lo siguiente: hago esto en la cabecera de la página y me devuelve la imagen inferior:

```
$conexion = new Conexion();
$sql = "SELECT id, fecha_hora, remitente, asunto FROM mensajes WHERE destinatario = :valor";
$stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':valor', $_SESSION['id_usuario']);
$resultado = $stmt->execute();

while($resultado = $stmt->fetch()) {
    echo $resultado['id'] . "<br>";
    echo $resultado['fecha_hora'] . "<br>";
    echo $resultado['remitente'] . "<br>";
    echo $resultado['asunto'] . "<br>";
}
```

[image: increíble]

COMO ES POSIBLE QUE PASE ESTO ????

Comment: `$conexion -> prepare($sql);` debería ir sin espacios `$conexion->prepare($sql);`

Comment: no, eso es indistinto parece tambien...

Comment: tal vez sea el `<th hidden>`. Deberia ser `<th style="display : hidden;">`, deberías comprobarlo al inspeccionar los elementos en el navegador y ver que la tablas esta oculta

Comment: no, eso también lo tengo en otras tablas y funciona perfecto... hay que ponerlo en el <th> y en el mismo campo <td> y se oculta la columna... anda bárbaro !!!. Igual, probe eliminando el hidden y sigue sin andar...

Comment: entonces podrian ser las clases de la tablas, debes inspeccionar los elementos en el navegador o revisar los log de php, en alguno de esos dos sitios debe estar la solucion

Comment: **¿Estás cerrando la tabla: `</table>`** al final de todo?

Comment: si, despues del cierre del </tbody> realmente estoy desconcertado mas que nada, teniendo en cuenta lo que dice Rene, de que pueden ser las clases de las tablas... le borre las clases y cree una tabla mas abajo puro html... sigue sin cargar nada !!!

Comment: Arriba te falta esto: `$resultado = $stmt->execute();` Si no funciona, prueba como muestro en mi respuesta. Me gusta más esa forma, es más clara y más fácil de depurar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo lo resolvería de este modo. Asumiendo que la consulta funciona y devuelve datos.

En la variable `$html` concatena también las otras etiquetas de tu tabla, antes de entrar en el bucle. Al salir cierras el `tbody` y la tabla.

```
$stmt ->execute();
//Creamos array con los datos
$arrDatos = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/**
  * Preguntamos si la consulta devolvió datos y si es así, los imprimimos
  * Otro aspecto interesante de PDO es que no es necesario usar rowCount
  * para saber si la consulta devolvió datos,
  * basta con verificar los mismos datos con un if, ya que si no devuelve nada
  * el valor de $arrDatos sería FALSE
 */  

if ($arrDatos)
{          

   /**
     * En la variable $html iremos concatenando una tabla
     * que se llenará  con los  resultados  de la  consulta
   */  

    $html="<table>";
    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $html.= '<tr>';
        $html.= '<td>'.$row["id"].'</td>';
        $html.= '<td>'.$row["fecha_hora"].'</td>';
        $html.= '<td>'.$row["remitente"].'</td>';
        $html.= '<td>'.$row["asunto"].'</td>';
        $html.= '</tr>';

    }
    $html.="</table>";
    /* Imprimimos la  tabla */
    echo $html;

}
else
{
    echo "No hay datos";
}
```

Comment: A. Cedano, funcionó perfecto !!! hice algunas modificaciones al código y lo acomodé un poco y funcionó !!!

Comment: Me alegro @MNibor. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Hola la variable $resultado no veo que la estes llenando con la información de la consulta prueba esto:

```
<?php
$conexion = new Conexion();
$sql = "SELECT id, fecha_hora, remitente, asunto FROM mensajes WHERE destinatario = :valor";
$stmt = $conexion -> prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':valor', $_SESSION['id_usuario']);
$resultado = $stmt->execute();
?>
```

Para que la variable $resultado contenga datos y ahora si realizas el recorrido por el while, nos cuentas como te fue y seguirte ayudando.

Comment: no... sigue igual... nada de nada

Comment: no deberia de estar pegado esto: destinatario=:valor

Comment: realiza un echo "<pre>"; var_dump($resultado); exit(); y mira como te trae la estructura de la información para enviarla por el while, revisa si tienes algún error.

Comment: eso es indistinto Francisco

Comment: si fuece indistinto podrias imprimir por pantalla la sentencia $sql y provarla sobre tu base de datos ... y verificar si arroja error o 0 record el problema parece mas de sintaxis o de asignacion que otra cosa.

Comment: o verificar que hay en la variable de sesion: $_SESSION['id_usuario']

Comment: si eso ya lo probe y recupera los registros que quiero... lo extraño es que el while funciona antes de colocar en la tabla... cuando lo inserto en el <tbody>
                    <?php while($resultado = $stmt->fetch()) { ?> ahi ya no funciona

Comment: pruebo el sql y $_SESSION['id_usuario']  y estan bien... es decir cargo en mysql los valores del $sql y el idusuario y devuelve los valores que necesito

Comment: el var_dump de $resultado me devuelve "boolean true" osea que tiene algo